# Setting up virtual box to connect to database server on host machine

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu inside virtual box installed in a Windows 7 host machine.

I'm currently developing a web application both in windows 7 and ubuntu (in the virtual box), the problem is, I always have outdated database content in ubuntu.

Code for both OS is easily updated, I could just pull fresh code from the repository for both the windows app and the one in ubuntu, but restoring database everytime data is inserted takes some time (DB size approx 9GB).

Is there a way to have the web application in **Ubuntu virtual machine** run by it's own application server (Apache) to point to the database server (Postgres) in **Windows host** running at port 5432.

The purpose is that whether I develop something in ubuntu or in windows, I can always have updated database content for both.

Comment: This is just TCP/IP guest to host networking. Nothing really to do with PostgreSQL.

Comment: okay? i don't exactly follow hehe enlighten me sir :)